# MAVEN : Run Multiple Maven Project using Maven Test

Tags: maven

I have 3 maven projects. Project1, Project2 & Project3. 
Project3 depends on Project1 & Project2 and Project2 depends on Project1.

For this I have added this in Project2 pom.xml file

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>Project2</groupId>
  <artifactId>Project2</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
     <dependency>
            <groupId>Project1</groupId>
            <artifactId>Project1</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

My pom.xml for Project3 is -

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>Project3</groupId>
  <artifactId>Project3</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>Project1</groupId>
            <artifactId>Project1</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
         </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>Project2</groupId>
            <artifactId>Project2</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

In the project 3 I have added testng.xml file to run the test. Now If I run this testng.xml file then all my test cases are running successfully. By If I tried to run test cases using maven test then its failing.

I have included testng.xml file in the pom file below dependencies to run testng test using maven -

```
<build>
        <!-- Source directory configuration -->
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <!-- Following plugin executes the testng tests -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.14.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Suite testng xml file to consider for test execution -->
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>Tng1.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <!-- Compiler plugin configures the java version to be used for compiling the code -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

It is showing error message -

`The POM for Project1:Project1:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available.
The POM for Project2:Project2:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available`

`Failed to execute goal on project Project3: Could not resolve dependencies for project Project3:Project3:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: Project1:Project1:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, Project2:Project2:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact Project1:Project1:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1`

Please Help !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install Project1 and Project2 in your maven repository first.

To do that launch the command

```
mvn clean install
```

in Project1 and Project2 directory (start with Project1 because Project2 has a dependecy to Project1)

**EDIT:**

For Jenking, I usually create a Root pom with module declaration. Maven will order you module by dependencies.

In your root pom you will have

```
<modules>
    <module>project1</module>
    <module>project2</module>
    <module>project3</module>
  </modules>
```

And in your submodule

```
  <parent>
  <groupId>com.myGroupId</groupId>
  <artifactId>project-root</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>
```

Yon can check http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html for full example

Comment: Now I have to do one more thing. I have to Run this project using Jenkins.. How to do this ?  I am providing the path of the Project3 pom.xml . But showing the same error message that was previously provided while running using maven test. Please Help !!!

Comment: I will try this, but is there a way where I can run this with the current pom ?

Comment: If you want to use your current pom you have to build project1 and project2 in Jenkins before project3.

Another way is to deploy project1.jar and project2.jar in nexus (or other maven repository)

Comment: Thanks for the reply !!! I will try the 1st option because I don't know how to deploy jars to nexus.