# Jenkins : Run Multiple Dependencies Maven Project

Tags: jenkins

I have 3 maven projects. Project1, Project2 & Project3. 
Project3 depends on Project1 & Project2 and Project2 depends on Project1.

For this I have added this in Project2 pom.xml file

```
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

      <groupId>Project2</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project2</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

      <dependencies>
         <dependency>
                <groupId>Project1</groupId>
                <artifactId>Project1</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
```

My pom.xml for Project3 is -

```
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>Project3</groupId>
      <artifactId>Project3</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

      <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>Project1</groupId>
                <artifactId>Project1</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
             </dependency>

             <dependency>
                <groupId>Project2</groupId>
                <artifactId>Project2</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            </dependency>
      </dependencies>
```

In the project 3 I have added testng.xml file to run the test. Now If I run this testng.xml file then all my test cases are running successfully.

I have included testng.xml file in the pom file below dependencies to run testng test using maven -

```
  <build>
            <!-- Source directory configuration -->
            <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
            <plugins>
                <!-- Following plugin executes the testng tests -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.14.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- Suite testng xml file to consider for test execution -->
                        <suiteXmlFiles>
                            <suiteXmlFile>Tng1.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                        </suiteXmlFiles>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
                <!-- Compiler plugin configures the java version to be used for compiling the code -->
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.6</source>
                        <target>1.6</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
```

Even these tests are running when I am trying to run this using Maven Test. **But when I tried to run this using jenkins then it fails and shows below error.**

```
[WARNING] The POM for Project1:Project1:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[WARNING] The POM for Project2:Project2:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.476 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-08-25T15:16:56+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 13M/114M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project Project3: Could not resolve dependencies for project Project3:Project3:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: Project1:Project1:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT, Project2:Project2:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact Project1:Project1:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Please Help !!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32198469/maven-run-multiple-maven-project-using-maven-test

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32198469/maven-run-multiple-maven-project-using-maven-test